# Usage of AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory in solr for suggestions

Tags: solr, lucene, search-suggestion

I have few doubts regarding the usage of AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory as lookupImpl in Solr suggester component.
ref: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester

1.) As AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory lookupImpl will build a lucene index for suggestions by generating n-grams for the suggestion field, will it still be a correct choice to choose this suggester implementation if the main index which is used for search is already having n-grams for the same field.

2.) Also, AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory returns duplicate results if multiple documents have the same value for suggestion field. How to handle this? Although choosing FST based suggester will prevent this, but it can't support infix search.